# multiple textures with same reference type

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

is it possible in CUDA programming to create and reference two textures with the same reference type? I tried to create two textures with reference type int4 and I got an error back (unspecified launch error).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Something else must be going on - if you post more code, someone might be able to help.